# Flash custom scrollbar

Tags: actionscript

I want to put text in a block, and design a custom scroll bar that will scroll the text in that very block. (while not scrolling forever, and I want the text to be scrolled with ease.)

Comment: Yea, like.. when people will scroll, i want the text to move fast at first but then kind of slow down until it stops, yea I guess easing :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to make an eased animation.  Check out TweenMax.  It's a great tweening library for AS2 and AS3.  There are many out there but this is a popular one.

http://www.greensock.com/

It allows you to tween things like so (AS3 example):

```
//Scroll the textBox upward when the user clicks the scrollDownButton
function onScrollDownButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  //TweenMax.to(objectToTween, tweenDurationInSeconds, tweenArguments);
  TweenMax.to(textBox, 0.5, {
    //Tween properties on the textBox like the y position
    y: textBox.y - 50,

    //Specify easing through an Easing class, which has methods to:
    //easeIn, easeOut, and easeInOut (these are packaged with TweenMax)
    ease: Expo.easeOut
  });
}
```